Is it possible to run repast simphony in an IDE other than Eclipse (e.g., Visual Studio Code)?
I am an active user of repast simphony in Eclipse, having run many simulation experiments with repast simphony in the past on my own Windows machine. I have recently acquired access to a new Windows computer system on which I would like to run some simulations with repast simphony. However, the new system does not come with Eclipse by default, and the process of adding new programs is non-trivial. Is it possible to set up and run repast simphony easily in any other IDEs to which I might already have access (e.g., Visual Studio Code)?
In reviewing https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastFAQ/RepastFAQ.html#_is_repast_simphony_available_for_android_or_ios, I see that some options are mentioned for running parts of repast simphony outside of an IDE. However, I am interested instead in trying to run repast simphony in another IDE than Eclipse, if such is possible.

This might be possible, although I have not tried it a very long time and it ultimately might not work. The eclipse install contains a jar with all the compiled and source code for Simphony. On macOS, that's typically here: /Applications/Repast Simphony 2.11.0/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/repast.simphony.bin_and_src_2.11.0/repast.simphony.bin_and_src.jar. You could try using that as a jar to compile against.
For running a model in the GUI, you only need to include the jars (in lib) and the compiled classes (in the bin directory) from the repast runtime (e.g., /Applications/Repast Simphony 2.11.0/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/repast.simphony.runtime_2.11.0). That said, I'm not sure the dependency discovery mechanism we use will work outside of eclipse (although it's not eclipse based), and I don't think a ReLogo or state chart model can be developed outside of eclipse.
To create a new model, you are probably best off creating that using the wizards in the eclipse install, and then trying another IDE.
